# Scrollview doesn't move up when keyboard appears several times

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, swift4

I've made 30 textfields and`var scrollview: UIScrollView` in `viewDidLoad()` and am trying to move up the whole scrollview up when keyboard covers textfield. `Delegate` of textfields and scrollview is already set. 
This code(down below) works and scrollview moves up when keyboard appears for the first time, but the problem is, when keyboard is opened for the second time or more, scrollview doesn't move up.I`ve been unable to solve this problem for several hours. Could anyone detect some faults in my code and give me correct answer? Im looking forward to any help!

The code I've written is this:

```
var activeField: UITextField?

func registerForKeyboardNotifications(){
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWasShown(notificaiton:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillBeHidden(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
}

func deregisterForKeyboardNotifications(){
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name:NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
}

@objc func keyboardWasShown(notificaiton: NSNotification){
    var info = notificaiton.userInfo!
    let keyboardSize = (info[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue.size
    let contentInsets: UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, keyboardSize!.height, 0.0)
    var aRect: CGRect = view.frame
    aRect.size.height -= keyboardSize!.height

    if let activeField = activeField{
        if !aRect.contains(activeField.frame.origin) == true{
            scrollview.contentInset = contentInsets
        }
    }
}

@objc func keyboardWillBeHidden(notification: NSNotification){
    view.endEditing(true)
}

func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool{
    activeField = textField
    registerForKeyboardNotifications()
    return true
}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField){
    activeField = nil
    deregisterForKeyboardNotifications()
}
```

Comment: do NOT call `deregisterForKeyboardNotifications` in `textFieldDidEndEditing`, but until view controller disappears

Comment: yes i tried to write these code in `viewWillDisapprear` but this method doesn't seem to be called when keyboard closes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

friend please try this piece of code. Hope it will work for you too. I am using this and it works well.

```
 override func viewDidLoad(){
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,selector: #selector(self.keyboardDidShow(notification:)),
    name: UIResponder.keyboardDidShowNotification, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,selector: #selector(self.keyboardDidHide(notification:)),
    name: UIResponder.keyboardDidHideNotification, object: nil)
}

//MARK: Methods to manage keybaord
@objc func keyboardDidShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    var info = notification.userInfo
    let keyBoardSize = info![UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! CGRect
    scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, keyBoardSize.height, 0.0)
    scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, keyBoardSize.height, 0.0)
}

@objc func keyboardDidHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    
    scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
    scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsets.zero
}
```

I have written this code for swift 4.0.

Comment: Thank you, this code worked perfectly. really appreciate your solution !
I really want to upvote this but sorry I haven't reached enough reputation to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Managing multiple textfield scrolling and adding multiple lines of code in every viewcontroller really occupied most of development time but luckly we have an alternative solution with less number of code use this [libarary](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager)
 you need to add only on line  in your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager().enable = true
```

this will handle your entire project keyboard

Hope this will help you

Comment: thank you for your solution. actually I'm such a beginner that i didnt know how to use library so it was a great chance for me to learn about it. Thanks!
(sorry I haven't got enough reputation to upvote your solution)

Comment: reputation not a matter if you get solution that's enough :)

Comment: IQKeyboardManager is not working with scroll views.

Answer (score 0):

> simply use IQKeyboardManager

- first install pod
- second import IQKeyboardManagerSwift in AppDelegate.swift
- third  write  IQKeyboardManager.shared.enable = true in 
  didFinishLaunchingWithOptions function.

@UIApplicationMain

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

  IQKeyboardManager.shared.enable = true

  return true
}}
```